# JMS MessageProducer.setTimeToLive() vs. TextMessage.setJMSExpiration()

Tags: java, jms

Is there a difference between calling `MessageProducer.setTimeToLive()` vs. `TextMessage.setJMSExpiration()`?

I can see from the documentation that [javax.jms.MessageProducer.setTimeToLive()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html#setTimeToLive(long)) says that it

> Sets the default length of time in milliseconds from its dispatch time that a produced message should be retained by the message system.

and that [javax.jms.Message.setJMSExpiration()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSExpiration(long)) says that it

> Sets the message's expiration value.

Those sound the same to me. Should I go ahead and set both to the same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a key difference, `MessageProducer.setTimeToLive()` sets the same message expiry time on all messages sent by that producer. On the other hand `TextMessage.setJMSExpiration()` sets message expiry time on a per message basis. The expiry time set on per message overrides the expiry set on `MessageProducer`.

JMS also specifies a way to set message expiry time when calling `MessageProducer.send` method.

```
void send(Message message, int deliveryMode,int priority, long timeToLive)
```

You can set message expiry on either `MessageProducer` or `TextMessage`. No need to set on both.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks. I was wondering if they had totally different purposes and you fully clarified! Thanks

Comment: @Kirby Actually if you try to set the expiration using Message#setJMSExpiration() it won't work, since the provider will always override it. Expiration can only be set via the MessageProducer, either for all messages using MessageProducer#setTimeToLive() or per message using MessageProducer#send(Message, int, int, long). Unfortunately the Java EE 5 Javadocs are not clear about that.

Comment: downvote - sorry, but this is simply wrong as @Kirby explains.

Answer (score 13):

You should not set expiration settings for `Message` (or `TextMessage`, as in your example). That text from Java EE 5 Javadocs is confusing, and it was improved in [recent versions](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSExpiration):

> This method is for use by JMS providers only to set this field when a message is sent. This message **cannot be used by clients to configure the expiration time of the message**. This method is public to allow a JMS provider to set this field when sending a message whose implementation is not its own.

That means that you should NOT use `Message#setJMSExpiration()` to set message expiration, since the provider will override that value when the message is sent.

You should instead use its `MessageProducer` to set the timeout for all messages using `MessageProducer#setTimeToLive()` or, if you only want to set the expiration for a particular message, do so using `MessageProducer#send(Message, int, int, long)` as shown in Shashi's answer. Only in this case does the "per-message" setting override the `MessageProducer`'s setting.